# Number Format Exception in Java Servlet

Tags: java, web

I have made a simple servlet in Eclipse running on Tomcat server.

I am running a simple java application which passes a string `message=20` to the servlet. The servlet gets the data. I am using

```
String name= request.getParameter("message");
```

to get the passed string. When I return the name value back to the application, I am able to get it back. But when I try to process the string name:

```
int val=Integer.parseInt(name);
```

I get `NumberFormatException`. I cannot figure out what the problem is. I have been able to get the value of name variable back from the servlet, but why can't I use it?

The Code I am using is as follows:

**CLIENT SIDE CODE**

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/DemoServer/demoservelet");

URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setDoOutput(true);

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream() ) );

out.write("message=20");
```

**SERVLET CODE**

```
String username = request.getParameter("message").toString();

int val=Integer.parseInt(username);  //get error msg on this line

response.setContentType("text/html");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("Passed val :"+ username+username.length());


}
```

I am getting error on the conversion. One more thing on return I am getting a length value of 4 which also does not make any sense?

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you debug to see exactly what the value of `name` is on that line?

Comment: And how did you pass the name and value?

Comment: What do you see if you print the value of name before you try to parse it?  You could enclose the printed value in quotes/brackets to make sure it doesn't contain whitespace.  System.out.println("[" + name + "]");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use GET-style parameter passing or PUSH-style parameter passing?

GET-style passing tacks the parameter on the end of the URL like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/DemoServer/demoservelet?value=20
```

A URL like this can be assembled fairly easily. You only need to change your URL-creation line, and can remove the two lines related to opening a BufferedWriter:

```
URL url = new URL(String.format("http://localhost:8080/DemoServer/demoservelet?value=%d", 20));
```

POST-style passing has to abide by the HTTP protocol, which is fairly similar to what you're using so far, save for the fact that all parameters must have a trailing newline character. Using your example:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()));

out.writeln("message=20");
```

You could also use a PrintStream, which would make formatting your parameters a little easier to handle if you need to change them:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(conn.getOutputStream());

out.printf("message=%d\n", 20);
```

Whether you use GET-style or PUSH-style is up to you, though it depends on the type of data you're passing along.

Answer (score 0):

you must to check if name is a valid numbre. name.match("^-?\d+$"); it returns true if it is a number

Comment: the value of the string is 20 i.e. on client side i write like this ("message=20"). On servelet side, I have been to get the value. As when I return back the value from servelet i am getting 20 in return which is fine.   But I cannot perform the conversion on that string . I hope u got my point. I will also post my code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must write the parameter as a parameter for it to be detected as one.

```
out.write("<param name=\"message\" value=\"20\">");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the value of output name,determine the name is a number,when the debug of check
values.